# Python dataframe merge on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-conditions

I have two data frames, and 3 conditions to create new data frame
1)df1["Product"]==df2["Product"] and df2["Date"] >= df1["Date"]
2)Now need to loop df2["Product"] sum(df2["Count"]) while checking df1["Count"] on each iteration for df2["Count"] == df1["Count"]

Example
df1["Product"][2] = "147326.A" and df1["Date"][2] = "1/03/22" and df1["Count"][2] = 4,
now we check df2 if there is match df2["Product"][1] == df1["Product"][2] and df2["Date"][1] >= df1["Date"][2], first condition are met now we need to sum() the df2["Count"] end on each iteration compare it to df1["Count"] if df1["Count"]== df2[Count] add to new data frame

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Date":["11/01/22", "1/02/22", "1/03/22", "1/04/22", "2/02/22"],"Product" :["315114.A", "147326.A", "147326.A", "91106.A", "283214.A"],"Count":[3,1,4,1,2]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Date" : ["15/01/22", "4/02/22", "7/03/22", "1/04/22", "2/02/22", "15/01/22","1/06/22","1/06/22"],"Product" : ["315114.A", "147326.A ", "147326.A", "91106.A", "283214.A", "315114.A","147326.A","147326.A" ],"Count" : [1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1]})
```

The following data should be a match:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Date" : ["01/03/2022"],"Product":["91106.A"],"Count":[2]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Date" : ["01/03/2022", "7/03/2022", "7/03/2022", "7/03/2022","7/03/2022", "7/03/2022"],"Product" : ["91106.A", "91106.A","91106.A", "91106.A", "91106.A", "91106.A"],"Count" : [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]})
```

Comment: kindly format your question properly, and add your expected output dataframe

Comment: Hello  sammywemmy, deeply apologises for the confusion, just trued to be as informative as I can will do that later today.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this in a list comprehension (within a `pd.DataFrame`):

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame([j.to_dict() for i, j in df1.iterrows() if
                    j["Count"] == df2[(df2["Product"] == j["Product"]) &
                                      (df2["Date"] >= j["Date"])]["Count"].sum()])
```

Splitting this up into lots of lines would look like this:

```
l = []

for i, j in df1.iterrows():
    if j["Count"] == df2[(df2["Product"] == j["Product"]) &
                         (df2["Date"] >= j["Date"])]["Count"].sum():
        x = j.to_dict()
        l.append(x)

df3 = pd.DataFrame(l)
```

Comment: Hello Rawson, thank you for the solution will test its later today with actual data.

Comment: Updated my post with data that should be match but its not.

Comment: Ah, you didn't mention before that you only want unique data.  Assuming you will drop rows if all columns are the same, you can drop the duplicates in `df2` first with this: `df2.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)`.  With this, the second option will also return one row in `df3`.